# NTFS partition mount but doesn't show any files

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning, ntfs, fdisk

The partition was bootable, but it's not anymore. I booted with an ubuntu live CD.

"fdisk /dev/sda3 -l" shows this:

```
Disk /dev/sda3: 626.4 GB, 626396585984 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 76155 cylinders, total 1223430832 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x6e697373

This doesn't look like a partition table
Probably you selected the wrong device.

     Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda3p1   ?  1936269394  3772285809   918008208   4f  QNX4.x 3rd part
/dev/sda3p2   ?  1917848077  2462285169   272218546+  73  Unknown
/dev/sda3p3   ?  1818575915  2362751050   272087568   2b  Unknown
/dev/sda3p4   ?  2844524554  2844579527       27487   61  SpeedStor

Partition table entries are not in disk order
```

Any advice on how could I address the issue? I would like to rescue the whole disk if possible.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the disk has failed or been corrupted. Fdisk doesn't recognize the partition table, but did its best to reconstruct one from what it sees, as you can see by the message this doesn't look like a partition table. A restore from backup or reinstall will probably be in order after testing the disk to ensure it is good.

Comment: I don't have a backup unfortunately.